# Something preventing php from seeing if a process exists by using file_exists on /proc/pid on some RHEL/CentOS installations

Tags: php, linux

#### What I am trying to do

The web application that I am developing relies on background workers for certain tasks and I've built a self-diagnostic suite for it that includes checking on the workers' health.

One of the steps includes checking if the process of the worker is still running.

#### Current implementation

`file_exists("/proc/$pid");`

#### The issue

This seems to work fine for most customers and on my dev machines (both on Ubuntu and CentOS), but I've had 2 reports (one using CentOS 6.7 the other RHEL 6.6) of the diagnostic always returning a negative result.

I cannot reproduce the issue on my systems, so I am wondering if there is any hardening that could cause this behaviour. Did anyone run into this before?

#### Workarounds that I have tried

Switching to ps -p to check on the process by pid (if it returns more than 1 line, then the process is running) - this works fine as long as SELinux is not enabled, so sadly this isn't a solution for me.

Hope that someone came across this before, please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was simply the open_basedir directive that blocked access to /proc.